# session issue - but is it session issue?

Tags: django, http, session, http-post, httprequest

I am stuck in this small issue. I have a page where the user needs to log in. after login everything is fine. but once the user is logged in, if he hits the address bar with `enter`, this error - `Key 'username' not found in <QueryDict: {}>` is coming and showing error on the page.
this is my code for logging in:

```
if request.path == '/cms/':
    request.session['username'] = request.POST['username']
    request.session['password'] = request.POST['password']
    #check for login
    if User.objects.exists():
        u=User.objects.get(id=1)
        if u.username==request.session['username'] and u.password==request.session['password']:
            #do some stuff here, cos i am logged in
```

now, if i reload the page, it is fine, but with `enter` not. should i save the POST data into session? what is happenning here actually?

thanks a lot

Comment: django has built in features to handle authenticating the `User` object https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: @dm03514, so what is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `request.POST` contain? It does not contain the username.  To find out what it contains you can print request.POST which should show up on your dev server, or you can log the value somewhere or you can enter debugger and inspect using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

python dictionaries have [`get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method for this case

`request.POST.get('username')`

If the key is not found it returns `None` by default instead of a `KeyError`

are you making a post request to your view?

```
<form method="post" action="/yoururlhere/">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="text" name="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

The above form would post the `username` and `password` fields.  I think it is truley important to read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ in its entirety, and learn how to use django built in user management.  Django provides User objects (which it looks like you are using) and provides all the necessary functions to manage their authentication.

It is important because:

1. It is easier than doing it manually, once you learn it
2. Because it is easier it is most likely going to be faster than manageing authentication yourself
3. It is less prone to error than doing it manually. DJango source code has lots of eyes looking at it and lots of tests covering it.  Please use the built in tools for the safety of your site.

Comment: oh, i thought ``request.POST`` does have the username. what does it do then?

Comment: @doniyor request.POST represents a requests POST data.  Are you making a POST request to the view? does your post request have `username` field?

Comment: yeah, it has. i am sending the data from my form with POST. what does ``get`` do? does it do more then ``POST``?

Comment: @doniyor `get` is a dictionary method http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Thanks, dude. i am taking ``get`` now and reading the docs. i still dont know the exact reason why i get this error. i am having the same form as you show in your update